# ColdFusion PDF "Open with" or "save file" prompt

Tags: coldfusion

How can I create a pop up that allows the user to "open with" or to save file as when dealing with coldfusion pdf's?

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to create it when this form is not actually mine and I am just using and prefilling a form that already exists.

```
<cfpdfform source="82040.pdf" action="populate">
   <cfpdfformparam name="cust ##" value=""> <!---Section1 Customer Number--->
</cfpdfform>
```

I was able to create this pop up by doing something like this:

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=test.pdf">
<cfdocument format="PDF" localurl="yes" 
    marginTop=".25" marginLeft=".25" marginRight=".25" marginBottom=".25" 
    pageType="custom" pageWidth="8.5" pageHeight="10.2">
<cfoutput><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>PDF Export Example</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
</cfoutput>
</cfdocument>
```

But am not sure how I can combine these two. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Per Request What I have tried:

```
<cfset tempFilePath = "c:/path/to/someUniqueFileName.pdf">
<cfpdfform source="82040.pdf" action="populate" destination="#tempFilePath#">
    <cfpdfformparam name="org" value="Yes"> <!---Above Section1 Original --->  <!---On--->
</cfpdfform>
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=Testme.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#tempFilePath#" deleteFile="false">
```

Comment: I don't see the answer there.. I am trying to make this form have the prompt `<cfpdfform source="82040.pdf" action="populate">
   <cfpdfformparam name="cust ##" value=""> <!---Section1 Customer Number--->
</cfpdfform>` It is all coldfusion and does not have html.

Comment: This is the link to the pdf I am prefilling http://www.flhsmv.gov/dmv/forms/BTR/82040.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, cfpdfform renders the result in the browser ie "inline". To return it as an attachment instead, save the content to a file or a variable. Then use `cfheader/cfcontent` to return it as an attachment.

**File:**

Use the "destination" attribute to save it to a file. To avoid conflicts with other threads be sure use *unique* file names. To automatically remove the temporary file when finished, set deleteFile="true"

```
<cfset tempFilePath = "c:/path/to/someUniqueFileName.pdf">
<cfpdfform source="82040.pdf" action="populate" destination="#tempFilePath#">
  ...
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=test.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#tempFilePath#" deleteFile="false">
```

**Variable:**

Use the "name" attribute to save the content to a variable. Though "name" is not listed in the documentation, [this bug report](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3040978) suggests it is just a documentation error.

```
<cfpdfform source="82040.pdf" action="populate" name="pdfContent">
... etcetera ...
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=test.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" variable="#toBinary(pdfContent)#">
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not have time for chat right now. However, it is pretty much what I posted above.  Can you update your question with the code you tried?

Comment: (Edit) You forgot to explain what is wrong with the result. What you have works fine for me.  Side note, only post the *minimum* code necessary to reproduce the issue. In this case, code populating a single field would do it.

Comment: That seems unlikely. Either there is something different in your actual code, or it is something simple like caching - which you can handle on your own. Start with the [simplified example in my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27869058/revisions). Create a simple test page with *only* that code - nothing else. You will see it works.  Then go from there. Obviously substitute a *real* path and *unique* file name for "c:/path/to/someUniqueFileName.pdf".